# Graphing a scatter plot or line graph with Mac Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following data:

```
Subject      Avg Calorie Intake     Avg Min in MVPA
  41              908.79                 25
  21             1050.43                 23.33
  15             2956.33                 64.16
```

How do I get three lines for each subject with the averages as the x and y axis?
It keeps giving me the x axis as the subjects and that's not what I want.

Comment: Your question is very confusing, so a little clarification will help: you're asking for 3 lines for each subject, but only providing one point (with an x coordinate and a y coordinate) for each subject, so you don't have enough info for 3 lines, only 3 points.

Answer (score 0):

You can specifically tell excel which axis you want the series to be located like this:

```
With xlApp.ActiveChart
  .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='sheet name'!R21C4:R46C4"
  .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='sheet name'!R21C5:R46C5"
  .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "='series name'"
  .SeriesCollection(1).axisgroup = Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary
End With
```

---

Post some of your code and I'll give you better direction.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when Excel is giving you trouble with how your data is being presented in a chart, you can use the following steps to better customize your data.

1. Insert Chart (e.g. Scatter), **while a blank cell is highlighted**.  This will create a completely blank chart, with no Excel assumptions about how you want your data displayed.
2. Select your chart, right click and Select Data.
3. Add Legend Entries (Series).
4. For a Scatter Chart, you can then select your Series Name, X Values and Y Values.  Using your sample data you could choose Subject for Series Name, Avg Calorie Intake for X Values and Avg Min for Y Values.